# Material-UI Menu component only last MenuItem onClick action is triggered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Recently I tried to implement a simple dropdown menu using MaterialUI(4.3.3)'s Menu and MenuItem components.

The onclick event on the MenuItem is not behaving correctly. When `console.log(id)` is called, every component is echoing the last element from sample array. I switched to ListItem, the problem is gone.

```
const Test = () => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const sampleArray = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    return (
        sampleArray.map(id => {
            let curID = id;
            return (<>
                <IconButton
                    aria-label="more"
                    aria-controls="long-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    onClick={event => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)}
                >
                    <MoreHorizIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                    elevation={0}
                    id="long-menu"
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    keepMounted
                    open={open}
                    transformOrigin={{
                        vertical: 'top',
                        horizontal: 'center',
                    }}
                    onClose={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
                >
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => {
                        setAnchorEl(null);
                        console.log(curID); // should be each individual id, but here always "test3"
                    }}>Test</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </>);
        })
    )
}
```

Is this the desired behavior for Menu? How to resolve it?

Comment: Try in map function before return add let curId=id; and use it  in onclick instead.

Comment: @Oleg Still the last element is printed. :( I will edit to add this line. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: try to use Index from map second parameter and access by index to it . let curIndex=index;

Comment: Sorry, can you push let as you did before in click function and not before return

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is the desired behavior. It's a little confusing: 
You have single state (anchorEl), which decides what is the anchor for **all** menus. 
When you click on a IconButton, you set the same AnchorEl to all menus. 
So when you open the menu, you actually open all 3 menus in the same place! 
The reason you always get 'test3' in the console, is because menu with the id test3 is rendered last and he overlaps the other menus.

---

To fix this, you need every menu to manage it's own state, so every menu will have it's own anchor:

```
const IsolatedMenu = props => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return(
  <React.Fragment>
    <IconButton
    aria-label="more"
    aria-controls="long-menu"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    onClick={event => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)}
    >
    <PriorityHighIcon />
    </IconButton>
    <Menu
    elevation={0}
    id="long-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    keepMounted
    open={open}
    transformOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'center',
    }}
    onClose={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
    >
    <MenuItem onClick={() => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
        console.log('curr id',props.id); // should be each individual id, but here always "test3"
    }}>Test</MenuItem>
    </Menu>

  </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

And than your Test component should look like that:

```
const Test = () => {
  const sampleArray = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

  return (
      sampleArray.map(id => {
          return (<>
            <IsolatedMenu  id={id}/>
          </>);
      })
  )
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]